# How should I understand the difference between a helping verb and an action verb?

Tags: american-english, british-english, auxiliary-verbs

I am a learner of English and found these definitions somewhere on the Internet about helping verbs and action verbs. Are they correct? They sound fine to me but I want to make sure because I have not learned English through rules.

**Helping verbs:**

> Helping verbs are usable in tenses to tell us time frames and we call
>   them as helping verbs because they do not have any meaning, they just
>   help us to inform about time frames of actions.

**Action verbs:**

> Action verbs help us to complete actions and helping verbs tell us
>   when those actions happened.

Comment: Tenses tell us time frames ( present, past and future) of actions ( walking, talking, running). 

We divide verbs into two parts: 
1- Helping verbs or auxiliary verbs.
2->Action verbs.

Helping verbs are usable in tenses to tell us time frames and we call them as helping verbs because they do not have any meaning, they just help us to inform about time frames of actions.

Action verbs help us to complete actions and helping verbs tell us when those actions happened.

Examples of helping verbs:
Is, are, am, does, do etc.

Examples of action verbs:
walking, talking, walk etc.

Comment: @WendiKidd, Please check the above comment, I pasted completely, which I copied last time when I was reading that.

Comment: Source means the url of the website , from where you got these definitions . The thing you just pasted in comment is almost same as you mentioned in your question . Any ways I think its correct, perfect and short description of both.

Comment: @Sushantp606, Thanks, I do not have source for now, I just read and saved it in a doc file so I could check later. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sentences were written by a non-native speaker. They have grammar errors. They should be...

> Helping verbs are used to tell us the time frame in which an action took place. We call them helping verbs because they do not perform an action. Instead they just help inform us about the time frames of actions.
>
> Action verbs describe actions and helping verbs tell us when those actions happened.

The definitions sound okay though. Helping verbs express tense (when an action took place) and action verbs express an action. So for example, in the sentence "He is finishing his homework", "is" is the helping verb and "finishing" is the action verb.

They can also be called "auxiliary verbs" and "main verbs". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb

Answer (score 0):

Helping verbs, also called auxiliary verbs (from Latin auxilium help, support) differ from normal verbs as they mainly serve to express tenses:

"will" for future 1, "would" for conditional 1, "have, has, had" for perfect tenses, the forms of to be/get for passive.

The forms of to do are also helping verbs for questions, negations and for use of emphasis or contradiction.